# open popup in IE

Tags: javascript

window.open(address,'Audio Player','width=340,height=30,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no, status=no,toolbar=no');

this is my code which is not working in IE. bu i want in IE.can any one suggest me to how

Comment: You. Want. To. Open. A. Window? (I mean...)

Comment: Explain 'not working'. What is the expected result? What is the result in IE? Do you get an error message? Which version of IE?

Comment: Did you check if IE has popup blocker enabled?

Comment: @aviraldg: There are perfectly valid reasons for wanting to open a new window from script.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have a space in the Window title in IE.  Change it to 'AudioPlayer'

Comment: To be clear, it is the window name, and the equivalent of `target=` on an anchor element, not the window title which is derived from the `title` attribute on the loaded page.